# Dijkstra, Bellman Ford application on map in double arrays

Tags: c, algorithm, dijkstra, shortest-path, bellman-ford

I have on input such a map:

```
int map_w = 40;
int map_h = 20;
char map[20][40] = {
    {'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'c', 'c', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'n', 'h', 'n', 'n'},
    {'n', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'n', 'n', 'c', 'n', 'n', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'n', 'c', 'n', 'n', 'h', 'h', 'n'},
    {'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'n', 'c', 'n', 'n', 'c', 'c', 'h', 'n', 'n', 'c', 'n', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'h', 'h', 'n'},
    {'h', 'h', 'h', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'h', 'h', 'n', 'c', 'n', 'n', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'n', 'c', 'c', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'n', 'h', 'h', 'n'},
    {'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'n', 'c', 'c', 'h', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'n', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h'},
    {'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'c', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'n', 'c', 'h', 'h', 'n', 'h', 'n', 'h', 'n'},
    {'n', 'h', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'n', 'n', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'n', 'h', 'h', 'n', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h'},
    {'c', 'c', 'n', 'c', 'n', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'n', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'n', 'n', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'p', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h'},
    {'c', 'c', 'n', 'c', 'n', 'c', 'c', 'n', 'n', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'n', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'n', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'c', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'n', 'h'},
    {'c', 'c', 'c', 'n', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'n', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'h', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'n', 'n', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'n', 'h', 'p', 'h', 'h', 'h'},
    {'c', 'c', 'c', 'n', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'n', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'h', 'h', 'c', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'c', 'c', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'c', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h'},
    {'c', 'c', 'n', 'c', 'c', 'n', 'n', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'h', 'c', 'h', 'h', 'n', 'n', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'n', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'n', 'h', 'n', 'c', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h'},
    {'c', 'c', 'n', 'n', 'c', 'n', 'c', 'n', 'c', 'n', 'c', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'n', 'h', 'n', 'c', 'h', 'h', 'n', 'h', 'n', 'h'},
    {'n', 'c', 'c', 'n', 'c', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'c', 'n', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'n', 'c', 'c', 'n', 'c', 'h', 'h', 'h'},
    {'n', 'c', 'n', 'n', 'c', 'n', 'c', 'n', 'c', 'p', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'n', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'n', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'n', 'c', 'h', 'h', 'h'},
    {'n', 'n', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'n', 'n', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'h', 'h', 'c', 'h', 'n', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'h', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'n', 'n', 'c', 'c', 'n', 'n', 'h', 'h', 'n'},
    {'n', 'n', 'n', 'c', 'c', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'c', 'h', 'h', 'c', 'h', 'n', 'c', 'h', 'n', 'n', 'c', 'n', 'n', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'n', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'n', 'n', 'c', 'c', 'n', 'h', 'h', 'n'},
    {'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'n', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'n', 'n', 'c'},
    {'n', 'n', 'c', 'c', 'n', 'c', 'n', 'n', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'c', 'c', 'n', 'c', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'c', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'c', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'c', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'c', 'n', 'n', 'c', 'n'},
    {'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'n', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'n', 'n', 'c', 'n', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'c', 'n', 'n', 'c', 'n', 'c', 'c', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n'}
};
```

here's the image of the map that how it looks like:
[image: http://i.snag.gy/GyCOD.jpg]

the chars in array correspond with each square, that means, gray is h and this is a stone this way i cant go. brown is normal path(c) which length is 1 green is forest(n) which length is 2

then there's d as dragon and p as princesses, i have to first find the shortest way to dragon and then to princesses and return the the exact shortest path..

So my question no.1 is, is there some way to put this input to some modified Dijkstra, or Bellman-Ford, or some different algorithm? Or i have to first make for every square a connection, that from square 1,2 i can go to 1,1 and the length is 2, and to 2,2 and length is 2, or i can simply somehow run the algorithms through the double array??

question no.2 Which algorithm do you suggest to use? I thought of Bellman Ford, although i have no negative squares, i need to return the exact path and this is very easy thanks to array pi, which is maintained in Bellman Ford, but I'm opened for any suggestions, as I'm just getting into theory of graphs.

Comment: Another option is Lee, that's what I would use for this problem. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lee_algorithm

Comment: You can run it as-is. You just need to have an `isWalkable()` function of some kind to generate possible moves, and something that tells you that `n` takes 2 steps (function or something simpler).

Comment: @Charlie Burns Lee looks, pretty good, is it easy to implement for 2D grids?

Comment: I also recommend A*. Or BFS/DFS if time isn't a factor.

Comment: @KEYSER Can you please be more specific about how to implement Dijkstra for 2D grids? Function for n takes 2 steps i already made, but quiet confused about isWalkable, its just a function which returns if its a stone or not?

Comment: @Ricsie Yes exactly. And then you have a `getPossibleMoves()` which calls `isWalkable()` in the (up to) 4 possible directions. You can then loop and iteratively or recursively fill a queue/list/stack (BFS/DFS/A* etc). This is one way of doing it.

Comment: @KEYSER Your idea looks very good and simple to me, so i just have to do a BFS/DFS/A* with a little modification with these functions getPossi... and isWalk...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, both Bellman-Ford and Dijkstra algorithm are overkill in here, since the edges all have a weight of 1.

Note that you can create an auxilary vertex for the cases of weight=2, so instead having edges of weights 1,2 - you will have more vertices and edges, but all of wight 1, basically this is done by replacing edges in the form `(u,v,2)` to: `(u,u',1)` and `(u',v,1)` - for every edge with weight 2. 

Note that at worst case it will give you `4|V|` vertices and `4|E|` edges, so it does not change the time complexity when it comes to big O notation.

In such graphs (unweighted/all edges weights the same), **BFS** is solving the problem efficiently and is much simpler to program than both BF and Dijkstra's algorithms.

An alternative is **[A* Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm)** with the **[manhattan distances heuristic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry)**, or a **[bi-directional search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bidirectional_search)**, which is usually faster than a normal BFS for large scales.

---

PS, note that you can create the graph 'on the fly', by creating a `next:V->(2^V x R)` function, that for a given vertex `v`, the result of `next(v)` will be all its connections and weights. By doing so, you actually create the parts of the graph you need dynamically, and not during some pre-processing,

Let's assume you have the following, and assuming the cost of 2 is if you move **to** a forest (and not from a forest).

```
     a  b
     ____
1:   c  h
2:   n  c
```

In here, you have the edges (in the original graph):

```
((1,a),(2,a),2), ((2,a),(1,a),1), ((2,a),(2,b),1), ((2,b),(2,a),2)
```

By applying the modification I suggested you get: 6 edges instead of 4, and the idea is you get the edges  `((1,a),(1_2,a_a),1) ((1_2,a_a),(2,a),1)` instead of `((1,a),(2,a),2)`, and similarly for `((2,b),(2,a),2)`.

Now, in here, your `next()` function will be:

```
next(1,a) = [((1_2,a_a),1)]
next(1_2,a_a) = [(2,a),1)] //dummy nodes also need an output...
next(2,a) = [((1,a),1), ((2_2,a_b),1] //two nodes in here, because you can move to 2 nodes.
next(2_2,a_b) = [((2,b),1)]
next(2,b) = [((2,a),1)]
```

---

Note, since the problem seems to be of small scale, and by your own words, you are a beginner - I think applying BFS will be the best solution for your problem. Once you are done with it, you will be able to improve to a more efficient algorithm - but IMO, you should start with the simplest one, which is BFS.

Comment: A* algorithm looks good, but quiet confused with the heuristic function, it looks too complicated for me as a beginner. also what will the function next return?

Comment: @Ricsie If I were you, I'd start with a simple BFS, it is much easier for beginners to implement than all other suggestions, but make sure you create all the edges at weight 1. I tried to explain better what I meant in the `next()` function, and how to create the edges of weight 1.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, It kind of opened my mind how to do it, thinking of doing your on the fly recreation of the graph with Bellman-Ford algorithm, have some experience with it, and hopefully it should work, the BFS is indeed very easy, but creating double grids from one looks a little complicating, also, dragon, princess grids have size of 0 steps so this would be kind of a problem too. Maybe if i can do the whole project this weekend next one i will try the Astar with Manhattan heuristics, it looks extremely efficient

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you give a close look at [A*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm).

It is an easy and yet efficient way of finding paths, especially in 2D grids.

Comment: What makes A* so good for 2D grids?  Seems like a more specialized algorithm would be better.

Comment: I'm on Vakhs side. It's easy to implement for 2D grids, and has (relatively) great performance.

Comment: I agree with amit's answer. A* + manhattan distance is a great choice for this kind of problems.

Answer (score 1):

If you were to represent the map as a graph explicitly, you'd have to identify the children of every node.  So you could fill that explicit representation programmatically: every node (i>0,j) connects to (i-1,j), (i,j>0) connects to (i,j), (i

Comment: I would rather skip the representation of the 2D grid to a graph

Comment: This is not needed to implement any search algorithm. It may be needed if you want to use an already implemented library, though.